# Is there any way to integrate a Delphi app into a WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, delphi, remote-desktop

We have Delphi code that displays data capture and edit forms, and would like to integrate that into a WPP app. Changes can be made to the Delphi code, to communicate with a C# service that enables communication between the two apps.

Something that has been mentioned is, at a low level, changing the parent window of a Delphi window from another Delphi window (maybe even the main app window) to another window, a WPF or WinForms window. How feasible is this? How can it be done?

I am also pondering somehow using the WPF Remote Desktop control, but connecting to a remote desktop server on the same machine somewhere. Once again, how feasible, and how?

Comment: Look at RemObjects Hydra. And look at COM technology: if you'd wrap Delphi services as COM Automation server, than C# has wizards to consume COM services into managed code

Comment: There sure is: https://www.dima.to/blog/?p=581

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm embedding wpf windows into my delphi app. Yes, it's the opposite way, but maybe you get inspired. I build some COM-Objects on both sides - c# and delphi, which are used for exchanging events/functions etc. To embed the windows i use [`HWndSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class.

If you want to embed a Delphi window into WPF, you can use the [`HWndHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class.

There is a good C-sample which can nearly direct translated to Delphi in MSDN. See [Walkthrough: Hosting a Win32 Control in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms752055%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also a good starting point is this article "[WPF and Win32 Interoperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms742522%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)".

Comment: There is something about setting the parent window of the embedded window is there not? This is at Win32 API level, where is matters not what produces a window, just that there is one.

Comment: It's a little bit more than setting some parent handles. The window messages need to be correct. Unfortunately WPF works a bit different, this makes it necessary to use HWndHost. When you are using it, it's just setting Host handle as Parent for the Delphi window. Depending on your Input requirements you need to implement the IKeyboardInputSink-Interface.

Comment: Another useful article on the subject : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms771352%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've never done it myself, but I've heard of RemObjects' Hydra framework, they do exactly what you want.

Check this out:
http://www.remobjects.com/hydra/

and an example on their wiki:
http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/Delphi_WPF_Sample_(Delphi)

Hydra itself will be a host application that can host both - WPF (managed) and Delphi (unmanaged) modules.

WPF Remote Desktop control is a bad idea in my view, users won't be happy with such experience.

Comment: That example shows a WPF plugin in a Delphi app, not what I asked about, i.e. a Delphi plugin in a WPF app.